# Rails 5, AJAX and Mailer ActionView::Template::Error (Multiple style attributes specified)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an error when I use AJAX and Mailer. The error vanishes if I remove the ReferralMailer line

#### Index View

```
= render partial: 'referrals/referral', collection: @referrals
= simple_form_for Referral.new, remote: true, validate: true, html: { id: :referral } do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.input :email, required: true, label: false do
    .input-group
      = f.input_field :email, required: true, class: "form-control"
      = button_tag(type: 'submit', data: { disable_with: t("helpers.please_wait") }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-success") do
        i.fa.fa-pencil
```

#### _referral.html.slim

```
= referral.email
```

#### Controller

```
class ReferralsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @referrals = Referral.all
  end

  def create
    @referral = Referral.create(referral_params)
    ReferralMailer.new_invite(@referral).deliver_now
  end
```

#### referral_mailer.rb

```
def new_invite(referral)
  @referral = referral
  mail to: @referral.email,
     subject: "You are Invited"
end
```

#### Error

```
Started POST "/en/referrals" for ::1 at 2018-03-05 15:01:10 +0700
Processing by ReferralsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "referral"=>{"user_id"=>"49", "email"=>"testss3@test.com"}, "button"=>"", "locale"=>"en"} (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Referral Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "referrals" WHERE "referrals"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "testss3@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]] SQL (2.8ms)  INSERT INTO "referrals" ("email", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "testss3@test.com"], ["user_id", 49], ["created_at", "2018-03-05 15:01:10.733755"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-05 15:01:10.733755"]](0.7ms)  COMMIT
 Rendering referral_mailer/new_invite.html.slim
 Rendered referral_mailer/new_invite.html.slim (25.5ms)
 ReferralMailer#new_invite: processed outbound mail in 66.2ms
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 135ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)

 ActionView::Template::Error (Multiple style attributes specified):::1 - - [05/Mar/2018:15:01:10 ICT] "POST /en/referrals HTTP/1.1" 500 2650
http://localhost:3000/referrals -> /en/referrals
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show the snippet with the multiple styles.

Comment: I added the index view where the form sits

Comment: That is not what I asked, though. The error message suggests that you render an element with multiple style attributes somewhere. Find and show that element.

Comment: The error might be in your SimpleForm configuration. Can you post that?

Comment: Can you also post the entire stack trace and tell us on which the line the error occurs?

Comment: The error disappears when I remove the ReferralMail

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a typo in new_invite.html.slim.

I had different verions of the file as new_invite1.html.slim, new_invite2.html.slim, etc. and changed them depending on the referral campaign. One had a typo which caused the error.